# How can I convert my powerpoint presentation to lucidchart?

Tags: powerpoint, lucidchart

There are lot of descriptions how can I add my lucidchart to
my powerpoint presentation.
For example
https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/integrations/microsoft-office-powerpoint
Is there any way to convert my powerpoint chart to lucidchart?
thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not software how-tos. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.